# How to print a char ** var from python LLDB

Tags: python, c, lldb

I'm trying to print out a char ** using the python LLDB lib.
To be clear it the char **argv from the main function in a C program.
It should have 3 strings in the array from the input.

When launching the C program and stopping right after
main(int argc, char **argv)
in xcode i can just do p argv[0] and p argv[1] and I get the correct arg strings to print.

In python I have a function to print the first 2 argv strings

```py
def print_argv(argv: lldb.SBValue, target:SBTarget):
    pointer = argv.Dereference()
    summary = pointer.GetSummary().strip('\"')
    print(summary)
    str_len = len(summary)
    next_str_address:int = pointer.GetLoadAddress() + str_len + 1
    pointer_type = pointer.GetType()
    addr = SBAddress(next_str_address, target)
    next_value = target.CreateValueFromAddress("argv", addr, pointer_type)
    summary = next_value.GetSummary().strip('\"')
```

But the second input isn't there.

I've tried a number of different ways but I can't seen to get the second string. I tried using the argv.GetChildAtIndex and that works for 0 but not 1 or 2. I noticed that the address are offset by the string length, so I've tried to update the pointers, again no luck. I check that the inputs are really there by printing out from the C program.

Edit:
Here is how to set up the call to the print function

```
debugger = lldb.SBDebugger.Create()
debugger.SetAsync(False)

target = debugger.CreateTargetWithFileAndArch (str(binary_path), lldb.LLDB_ARCH_DEFAULT)
assert target, "Failed to create target"

target.BreakpointCreateByName ("main", target.GetExecutable().GetFilename())

launch_info = lldb.SBLaunchInfo(str_args)
launch_info.SetWorkingDirectory(os.getcwd())
error = lldb.SBError()
process = target.Launch(launch_info, error)

assert process, "Failed to launch process"
for _ in range(1000):# Putting an upper limit on the number of functions to trace
    state = process.GetState()

    if state == lldb.eStateStopped:
        for thread in process:
            function_name = frame.GetFunctionName()             
            frame = thread.frames[0]
            if function_name in function_names:
                for arg in frame.arguments:
                    if arg.name == "argv":
                        print_argv(arg, 3, target)

    process.Continue()
```

Solution:
Turns out you need to use can_create_synthetic==True.

`child = argv.GetChildAtIndex(1, lldb.eNoDynamicValues, True)`

Comment: How are you calling ```print_argv()```?

Comment: I've Added the setup to the questions. Thanks.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that GetChildAtIndex needs to have  can_create_synthetic set to True, then the values show up.

This seems to be true of stack allocated arrays too. I tried this C code:

```
void bar(char **blargh, int len){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        printf("%s\n", blargh[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *foo[] = {"one", "two", "three"};
    bar(foo, 3);
}
```

and it has the same result that can_create_synthetic is required to get at values other than the first. An array of simple types like ints doesn't change this either.

The docs don't really explain much, other that to say that you may need it for indexes after 0.

https://lldb.llvm.org/python_api/lldb.SBValue.html#lldb.SBValue.GetChildAtIndex

> Pointers differ depending on what they point to. If the pointer points
> to a simple type, the child at index zero is the only child value
> available, unless synthetic_allowed is true, in which case the pointer
> will be used as an array and can create ‘synthetic’ child values using
> positive or negative indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a general C vrs. debuggers problem since C allows unsized arrays it gives the debugger no hint about how to inspect.  As you have found, to work around this lldb will auto-resize unsized arrays dynamically for you, if you tell it that it can create "synthetic children" to represent the elements.

But since you also KNOW the size of the array (`argc`) there's a more straightforward and "correct" way to do this as well:

lldb's SBType has an `SBType::GetArrayType(uint64_t size)` API that will return the type of a fixed size array of a given size from any C type.  So the easy way to implement your printer is to pass both `argc` and `argv` to your print function.  Get the pointer type from the `argv` variable as you have done, and then make an array type with `argc` elements from it using the `GetArrayType(argc.unsigned)` call on your pointer type, and use that instead of the pointer type in `CreateValueFromAddress`.

Then you will get an array that naturally has the right number of children, and you won't risk accidentally fetching too many elements, etc.  It's also less magical, which is useful if you're going to have to figure out how this works again after enough time has passed that you've forgotten about the magic...

Comment: Thanks for having a look Jim. Yes clearly you shouldn't start randomly accessing values in an array with out knowing the size.  The main problem that I was having was that the Python GetChildAtIndex call was not retrieving the child, even though it was clearly there. It's still not clear to me what can_create_synthetic in GetChildAtIndex is about, but in this case it was needed. All the other pointer nonsense was trying to work around the problems with GetChildAtIndex.

Comment: When you are using an unsized array, lldb can't tell from the type how many children it should have.  So lldb says it has no "natural" children  unlike, say, `int[5]`.  lldb has another system for making "synthetic" children from a value - for instance `a_std_vector[0]` doesn't actually exist in the layout of a `std::vector` type, but lldb knows where the 0th element actually is so it makes a "synthetic child" to represent it.  Similarly, lldb can make "synthetic" children for any element of an unsized vector, but it won't do that unless you tell it it's okay to make synthetic children.

Comment: Synthetic children are discussed in more detail here: https://lldb.llvm.org/use/variable.html#synthetic-children

Comment: Thanks Jim. That makes sense. Just courious why it works in Xcode's lldb?

Comment: The Xcode Locals window is a viewer for SBValues so if they can figure out that something is unsized, they can use the synthetic child generation same as you are.  However, if I make a hello world "Command Line Tool" project, run it passing some arguments, and turn out `argv` in the Locals window, I only see the one element - the first.  So it doesn't look like anybody's fixing up that part.